# can we find a place where variable's value was change in watch list in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Hi I tried to debug one large application and value was change from some where i can see this in watch list so my question is can we see the place where this value was change ,yes we can do it by following function or code but can we have any easy way for that? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this page https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/break-when-value-changes-data-breakpoints-for-net-core-in-visual-studio-2019/ it should be as easy as clicking on the variable in Locals window and setting "Break when value changes".